# Add an IBAction to a UIBarButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uibarbuttonitem

I programmatically created a UIBarButton and I want it to segue to another viewController. I tried it with the following code, and it gave me an error. (If you would like me to post the error I can.)

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Comment: What error it is showing ?

Comment: If you're doing this for iOS, you want to pick up your image from the app bundle.  @"/users/mike/Desktop/myPic.png" isn't going to do it on a mobile device.

Comment: Your receiving method is looking for a sender, but the selector isn’t set up to send it. I think you need to add a colon after myAction in the @selector and add the sender as the object e.g. @selector(myAction:) withObject:buttonPressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method declaration doesn't match your `@selector` - Your method accepts a parameter (sender), so your selector is `myAction:`.  Your code should be

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Also, your image load won't work on the device because the path isn't available - you will need to load it from the bundle.

And, I don't know what functionality you are looking for with the button, but if it is a "tap" you should use event `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` rather `UIControlEventTouchDown`

Comment: Got It. How can I segue from one viewController to the next without using the segue Identifier, but using something else, ex. viewController's title?

Comment: How do you want to use the viewController's title?  Do you want to use that as the segue identifier?

Comment: Meaning, is there any other way of segueing to another viewController without having a segue identifier?

Comment: Not if you want to use a segue.  You can use `presentViewController` or you can push a view controller directly onto a navigation controller if you don't use a segue

Comment: You should ask another question with specific details of what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replace this line

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

With that line

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Comment: You need the : behind myAction... Like (myAction:)